# Text in ListView messed up when scrolling when using getView() with ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I have an odd problem where my `ListView` will correctly display the list items that are populated when the View is initially created, but when I start scrolling, the positions change on some items and do not reflect their position in the list.

Here's my code:

```
private class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        this.mContext = context;

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.assignment_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.colorStrip = (ColorStrip) convertView.findViewById(R.id.assignment_list_color_strip);
            holder.titleLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
            holder.descriptionLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_description);
            holder.dueLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_due);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        assignmentsCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String title = assignmentsCursor.getString(1);
        short course = assignmentsCursor.getShort(2);
        String desc = assignmentsCursor.getString(3);
        long due = assignmentsCursor.getLong(4);

        holder.titleLabel.setText("Pos: " + position + " | " + title);
        holder.colorStrip.setColor(colors.get(course));
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorsLight.get(course));
        String dueString = getDateString(due);
        holder.dueLabel.setText(dueString);
        holder.descriptionLabel.setText(desc);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View arg0, Context arg1, Cursor arg2) {}

    @Override
    public View newView(Context arg0, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2) { return null; }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() { return true; }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() { return 2; }
}
```

You can a see a video of my problem here: http://youtu.be/KzyTLSsDeJk In the video you can see that the list item at position 7 is changing a bunch as I scroll, and then the list seems to restart at 0 on item number 8. What the ListView *should* be showing is "Pos: 0", "Pos: 1"..."Pos: 8", "Pos: 9", and so on.

The colors are also messed up from position 8 on through the end of list. The background color is always supposed to be lighter version of the strip along the left-hand side of the list item.

**EDIT:**
In the video, you can see that the positions getView gets passed (which are reflected in the title TextView in each list item) are fine through the end of what is initially visible (through "Pos: 6 | ...") on the screen (without scrolling), but once I scroll down, everything that comes up next is messed up.

Here's a representation of the first TextView in each of the list items (what's in parenthesis are my comments):

Pos: 0  | Read Chapter 1 (good)
Pos: 1  | Fill out Knowledge Box (good)
Pos: 2  | Essay on Chapter 1 (good)
Pos: 4  | Read Chapter 2 (good)
Pos: 5  | Put more paper in binder (good)
Pos: 6  | Do Lesson 1 (good)
Pos: ## | [varies when scrolling] (starts off correctly at Pos: 7, but as I scroll more it changes wildly)
Pos: 0  | Read Chapter 1 (should be Pos: 8)
Pos: 1  | Fill out Knowledge Box (should be Pos: 9)

Pos: ## is the item that is initially just off-screen, but when I scroll the position number changes (see the video).

**EDIT 2:** Here's my ViewHolder class:

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    private static ColorStrip colorStrip;
    private static TextView titleLabel;
    private static TextView descriptionLabel;
    private static TextView dueLabel;

    public ViewHolder() {}
}
```

**EDIT 3:** Just for kicks, I stopped using my ViewHolder (and used the inefficient method of running findViewById() each time) and my problems all went away. All of TextViews are all being assigned the appropriate values, and the colors look good, too. Any ideas what could be wrong with my implementation of my ViewHolder?

Comment: What behavior are you expecting instead?

Comment: I want the ListView items to go 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9..., not 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,... If you watch the video, you can see the problem better than I can explain it. Where it says "Pos: # | (text)" (in the video), # is the position number that getView is being passed. In the video you can see that the list item at position 7 is changing a bunch, and then the list seems to restart at 0 on item number 8.

Comment: @m0skit0 Just look at what I added to my question, it's a little more clear than my previous comment. ;)

Comment: What is `assignmentsCursor` and how do you get it? Are you somehow modifying this `Cursor`? Can you show your `ViewHolder` declaration?

Comment: Is there any reason for for implementing the `getViewTypeCount` method? How about the `hasStableIds` method?

Comment: I strongly think your problem is either `holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();` (this is why it works fine on loading) or what Luksprog is mentioning.

Comment: @m0skit0 I actually added getViewTypeCount() (planning on using this soon) and hasStableIds() after I was already having this problem. hasStableIds() I thought would be good to return true for because my assignmentsCursor is a database query, where each row has a unique id. I'll add my ViewHolder class to my question.

Comment: Where's your ViewHolder class? Inside which class? Keep in mind that using static fields means this class can only hold ONE set of values.

Comment: Both my ViewHolder and custom CursorAdapter classes are subclasses of of my ListFragment.

Answer (score 0):

I think for assigning values of cursor you should use bindView() and newView() methods instead of getView().

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you are not using `CursorAdapter` as you should be using. In `CursorAdapter` you have to inflate the view inside `newView()` and return the `view` which will be passed to `bindView()` for binding the view with data from the cursor. You can check a demo project from [here.](https://github.com/lalit3686/CursorAdapter) to make sure how you can implement your `CursorAdapter`. Also you can check many tutorials for `CursorAdapter`, one of them is [this one](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/).

Comment: I changed it to use newView() (where I inflated the view) and bindView() (where I took the Cursor it provided and assigned the stored values to the corresponding TextView using my ViewHolder), but it still does the same thing. However, when I stopped using ViewHolder, my problem was (mostly) resolved. See what I added to my question for all the details.

Answer (score -1):

remove if condition from getView() method like this.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;


        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.assignment_list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.colorStrip = (ColorStrip) convertView.findViewById(R.id.assignment_list_color_strip);
        holder.titleLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        holder.descriptionLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_description);
        holder.dueLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_due);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    assignmentsCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    String title = assignmentsCursor.getString(1);
    short course = assignmentsCursor.getShort(2);
    String desc = assignmentsCursor.getString(3);
    long due = assignmentsCursor.getLong(4);

    holder.titleLabel.setText("Pos: " + position + " | " + title);
    holder.colorStrip.setColor(colors.get(course));
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorsLight.get(course));
    String dueString = getDateString(due);
    holder.dueLabel.setText(dueString);
    holder.descriptionLabel.setText(desc);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be a temporary test or a permanent solution?

Comment: If that's a permanent solution, that is a very inefficient solution. Perhaps you should see this portion of the video "The world of ListView" from Google I/O 2010: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=wDBM6wVEO70#t=414s

Comment: Once, my problem was solved using this so I suggested, but Thanks for your guide. now I can understand after seeing video. Thanks!